# QPX Express query error

Tags: php, web, google-qpx-express-api

My request was being processed correctly, I tried to get custom result like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search
?key=MY_API_KEY&fields=tri‌​ps(tripOption(saleTotal,slice(segment(leg(arrivalTime,departureTime,origin,destin‌​ation,originTerminal,duration,operatingDisclosure)))))
```

But it's producing the following error:

```
{ "error":
    { "errors":
        [ {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalidParameter",
        "message": "Invalid field selection trips(tripOption(saleTotal,slice(segment(leg(arrivalTime,departureTime,origin,destination,originTerminal,duration,operatingDisclosure)))))", "locationType": "parameter", "location": "fields" } ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid field selection trips(tripOption(saleTotal,slice(segment(leg(arrivalTime,departureTime,origin,destination,originTerminal,duration,operatingDisclosure)))))"
    }
}
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Comment: So, did you solve it? If yes, it would be good to post an answer here. If it's no more relevant, please delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `fields` parameter contains some weird characters, namely `\u200c`, which is [the Unicode *Zero Width Non-Joiner*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm).

You can see it in the `message` field of the response. Just remove those characters. It's possible that they're not visible in your editor, maybe try it rewrite while string manually.

Comment: now it's not showing \u200c but invalid fields error is still there

Comment: @NaveedKhan I see. So could you update your question with the new response, please?